# オーバーフロー、アンダーフローの用語の使い方と、それに類似する用語について

Tags: 専門用語

### 質問

しばしば負のオーバーフローのことをアンダーフローと呼んでしまうという誤解がありますが、それに類似する話として質問があります。

とあるプログラムにおいて「日時」を扱っているのですが、一般的に時刻は hh:mm:ss で、`0 <= hh <= 23`, `0 <= mm <= 59`, `0 <= ss <= 59` のような範囲があると思います。最小の時刻は `00:00:00` で最大の時刻は `23:59:59` というように。

このとき、便宜的にその範囲を超えて値を指定できる機能を作りたいとします。

例えば、`06:10:50` の30秒後を `06:10:80` と指定できるような機能です。この指定が行われたとき、時刻を `06:11:20` に正規化したいという具合です。

今回質問したいのは、その実装についてではなく、用語についてです。

このように「秒」が 59 を超えていることを指して、「秒の値がオーバーフローしている場合」という表現は適切なのでしょうか。「秒が59を超えている場合」を指す適切な専門用語がないのかと思って質問させていただきました。

また同様に、`1970/09/01` のような日付があるとき、`1970/09/00` を `1970/08/31` として扱う、というようなことがあると思いますが、これに対して「日の値がアンダーフローしている場合」という表現は適切なのでしょうか。これは不適切に思いますが、だからといって「日の値が負のオーバーフローが生じている場合」のように言うのもおかしいと思っています（`00` は負ではないので）。

- 時刻や日付が、通常の日時表記の値の範囲外になる場合のことを指す適切な用語があれば教えていただきたいです。
- 前述のように、これらを「オーバーフロー」または「アンダーフロー」と表現するのが不適切であれば、それが如何に不適切であるか（誤用であるか）について説明していただきたいです。

そもそもオーバーフローという用語が何を指すかという話にも立ち入りそうですが、このような疑問を持っている私にアドバイスをいただければ幸いです。

### 背景

とあるプロジェクトで共同開発しているのですが、そのプロジェクトのドキュメントに別の方が「秒の値がオーバーフローしている場合」、「日の値がアンダーフローしている場合」のように記述していて、より適切な表現がないか気になったという背景があります。

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow#Definition_variations_and_ambiguity

Comment: 開発チーム内での用語の使い方から話が始まったようですが、であれば、チーム内の人と話し合って皆さんが納得できる表現を使うのが良いと思うのですが。事情がよくわからない赤の他人が個人的意見を言っても聞いてもらえないような気がします・・・が、あえて私の個人的意見を言わせてもらえれば、今回の日時の話で「オーバーフロー」「アンダーフロー」というのは違和感ありありで、範囲外/範囲内とかの方が適切だと思います（kunif さんの意見に同意）。

Comment: 「秒が59を超えている場合」について述べるべき場面では「秒が59を超えている場合」と単にそのまま具体的に書けば良いような…？
何か適切な用語があるのか否かは知りませんが，例え存在したとしてもそれがこのように質問しなければ出てこないような語なのであれば，それをドキュメント等に用いれば結局読み手が「この言葉はつまり実際どういう意味なん？」ってなるような気がしますし．

Comment: 皆さんから意見を頂き、WebSurfer さん fana さんの仰る通り「範囲外」や「超えている場合」のように言ってしまうのが適切そうに思えてきました。

Comment: 個人的にはこういう言葉の定義を気にすること自体に違和感ありありですね。言葉はただのコミュニケーションツールであり、相手に伝わればいいもの。伝わりそうになければ万人に伝わる表現があればそれに変えるか、定義を明確にすればいいだけです。
今回はwikipediaすら定義が曖昧だと言ってるものなので、自前の定義を明確にするか、書いた人の主観に任せるべきで、誰かの主観に基づく違和感とかよく分からないもので文句を言うべきではありません。

Comment: 言葉選びに面倒さ(?)があるならば「 `59 < ss` の場合」って式で書けば明瞭なのでは．

Answer (score 2):

まあ普通に [c](/questions/tagged/c) プログラマがオーバーフローアンダーフローというときは特定ビット数サイズの整数なり浮動小数点数なりにおいて
オーバーフローは絶対値が大きい方向に表現できなくなった場合
アンダーフローは絶対値が０方向に精度が失われる場合

カレンダーに関しては下記のようなプログラムを普通に書きますし、動作保証されているはずです。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    struct tm t1 = {
        50, 10, 6, /* 06:10:50 */
        30, 2-1,  2023-1900, /* 2023/Feb/30 */
        /* omit following member */
    };
    t1.tm_sec += 30;
    time_t t2 = mktime(&t1);
    printf("%s\n", ctime(&t2));
}
```

なので、これをオーバーフローとかアンダーフローとか呼ぶのは違和感があります。あえて言うなら「非正規表現」とか「非厳密表現」とでも言いましょうか。例えば [java](/questions/tagged/java) の [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) クラスの解説とか。

ちなみにこの辺の関数の仕様上はうるう秒には標準対応しているので秒は [0, 60] が有効範囲とされています。うるう秒を実装しているかどうかは別問題。

Comment: 冒頭のオーバーフロー、アンダーフローの説明はその通りだと思います。それ以外の文脈で（今回のように）使われると違和感がありました。また、Java の Calendar クラスの説明文も参考になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

使用しているコンパイラ/インタプリタ/シェル他ツールなどでそれらの値を指定した時にどのようなエラーメッセージが表示されるかで決めると良いでしょう。
それなら根拠は明白であり、仕様であると言えるのでは？

例えばこんなメッセージが表示されます。

- C#
  `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2001, 13, 1);`では
  `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.'`
- Python
  `x = date(2001,13,1)`では
  `ValueError: month must be in 1..12`
  あるいは月が範囲内で日が0や40だと`ValueError: day is out of range for month`

おそらく`範囲内`/`範囲外`, `正常値`/`異常値`, `有効値`/`無効値`といった対比で表現されるのでは？

オーバーフロー/アンダーフローは日付時刻の変数をカウンタやインデックスとして兼用している場合に、それらの用途として取り扱った場合には言えなくもないでしょうが、微妙に違和感のある表現ですね。

---

あと構想されている内容では、[TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-7.0) とか [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) 等の2つの時刻の差とか経過時間を計算するためのオブジェクト/クラスの仕様とかも参考になるのでは？

Comment: エラーメッセージや仕様書から言葉を選ぶべきとのこと、参考になります。オーバーフローのような表現に拘らずに「範囲外」とするのが妥当な表現のように思えてきました。

Answer (score 1):

整数の理屈を日付には当てはめることについてはまず脇に置いて、「オーバーフロー」という用語の意味にブレがあることを説明します。

プログラミング言語 C の仕様書では整数が大きくなりすぎて一周して小さくなるような挙動 (いわゆるラップアラウンド) が規定されている状況を「オーバーフローしない」と言い切っています。 表せる範囲外になって結果が**未定義**になるときがオーバーフローであり、一旦は範囲を超えても結果が規定されているのはオーバーフローではないのです。

しかしこれはあくまでも C の仕様書における用語法であって、ラップアラウンドしようがしまいが上限を超えたときをオーバーフローと呼ぶのはごく普通にあることですし、大雑把な概念はともかくとして細かな挙動の部分では分野によって違う意味を持つこともある一例と言えるでしょう。

ひとつの文書の中で**一貫した意味付けをする**のであれば近い意味合いで使われている用語を持ってくるという選択も悪いわけではありません。 ただ、その意味付けを読者が読み取れなければ意味がありませんから、ピッタリと当て嵌まるとは言えない用語を使うのであれば用語の意味を定義する項目を設置するべきですし、頻出する概念でないなら冗長でも説明的な言い回しにするのが好ましいと思います。